# Find corresponding product combination according to user's selection

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, ionic3

This corresponds to an ecommerce site.

I have the following JSON corresponding to a list of combinations (sizes, colors, etc) valid for a certain product:

```
[
  {
    "id": 7,
    "price": 12,
    "stock": 100,
    "options": [
      {
        "attribute_value_id": 3,
        "attribute_value_name": "Blue",
        "attribute_id": 1,
        "attribute_name": "Colores",
        "disabled": false,
        "attribute": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Colores"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "attribute_value_id": 32,
        "attribute_value_name": "M",
        "attribute_id": 4,
        "attribute_name": "Talla Superior",
        "disabled": false,
        "attribute": [
          {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Talla Superior"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 17,
    "price": 7.2,
    "stock": 12,
    "options": [
      {
        "attribute_value_id": 2,
        "attribute_value_name": "Cream",
        "attribute_id": 1,
        "attribute_name": "Colores",
        "disabled": false,
        "attribute": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Colores"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "attribute_value_id": 38,
        "attribute_value_name": "XL",
        "attribute_id": 4,
        "attribute_name": "Talla Superior",
        "disabled": false,
        "attribute": [
          {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Talla Superior"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 20,
    "price": 528,
    "stock": 44,
    "options": [
      {
        "attribute_value_id": 8,
        "attribute_value_name": "Purple",
        "attribute_id": 1,
        "attribute_name": "Colores",
        "disabled": false,
        "attribute": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Colores"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "attribute_value_id": 29,
        "attribute_value_name": "S",
        "attribute_id": 4,
        "attribute_name": "Talla Superior",
        "disabled": false,
        "attribute": [
          {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Talla Superior"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 21,
    "price": 401,
    "stock": 37,
    "options": [
      {
        "attribute_value_id": 3,
        "attribute_value_name": "Blue",
        "attribute_id": 1,
        "attribute_name": "Colores",
        "disabled": false,
        "attribute": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Colores"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "attribute_value_id": 35,
        "attribute_value_name": "L",
        "attribute_id": 4,
        "attribute_name": "Talla Superior",
        "disabled": false,
        "attribute": [
          {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Talla Superior"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I require the following: if the user indicates that he wants the product in color "Blue" and size "L" (ids 3 and 35 respectively) based on this array look for which option has both features so that I can then know what stock and price there is for that combination.

I can't find how to do that in JavaScript/Typescript.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

U can do something like this.

```
const found = data.find(
      (item) =>
        item.options[0].attribute_value_name === 'Blue' &&
        item.options[1].attribute_value_name === 'L'
    );
    console.log(found && found.price);
```